# HTTP Post in angular 2 with Rest micro service

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to implement post request in angular 2 with the Rest API created .

My form is not being loaded and I am unable to make a post request to my API.

I am getting this error in my console

[image]

### Below shown is my Rest microservice code

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkByCredential", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkLoginByName(@RequestBody Users user) throws Exception{

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Users useObj1 = 
userRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword(user.username,user.password);
    return(mapper.writeValueAsString(useObj1));
}
```

### Below shown is my angular 2 code snippets

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BasicService } from './basic.service';


@NgModule({

  declarations  : [AppComponent ],
  imports       : [BrowserModule,HttpModule,FormsModule ],
  providers     : [BasicService],
  bootstrap     : [AppComponent ]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BasicService } from './basic.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h2>Login</h2>
    <form role="form">
      <div ng-control-group="credentials">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          #username
          id="username"
          ng-control="username"
          required>

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          #password
          id="password"
          ng-control="password"
          required>
      </div>

      <button (click)="checkByCredential(username,password)">Login</button>

    </form>`

})
export class AppComponent {
  title :string;
  data:any;

  constructor(private MyService: BasicService){
        this.title="Angular Service";

 checkByCredential(username: string, password: string) {
  this.MyService.checkByCredential(username, password).subscribe(users => this.data = users);
}

  }
}
```

### basic.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BasicService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  checkByCredential(username: string, password: string) {

  const user = { username: username, password: password };

  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  return this.http
    .post('http://localhost:8080/checkByCredential', user, { headers: headers }) 
    .map(result => result.json())
}
    }


}
```

can anybody please guide how to implement the post request with my ReSTAPI ,so that when i submit my form data it should authenticate the credentials from  my API

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in your `AppComponent` class. Use as below `AppComponent` class :

```
export class AppComponent {
  title: string;
  data: any;

  constructor(private MyService: BasicService){
    this.title="Angular Service";
  }

  checkByCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    this.MyService.checkByCredential(username, password).subscribe(users => this.data = users);
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried the same code snippet but i am getting the below error in my console

Comment: please help me to resolve the issue..i just edited my question and posted screenshot of the error..please verify

Comment: please find the screenshot for the error in my edited question.

Comment: i am getting a status of 400 for the post request.

Comment: please help me out with this post request

Comment: Make sure that your server is running and `http://localhost:8080/checkByCredential` is valid URL. Also enable `cors` at your server so that URL is accessible from your application.

Comment: yes my server is running and also i have cors enabled .can you please send me a demo plunker